# How to Avoid Adding Duplicated Item To List Of Multiple Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list Called ITEMS of following type

```
public class ABC
(
    string itemName{get;set;}
    int parentID{get;set;}
    List<ABC> Child {get;set;}    
)
```

So as `Class ABC` shows List ITEMS can have  `List<ABC> Child` and That `List<ABC> Child` can have another `List<ABC> Child`.
 Here is the question;
If I want to add new Item of type `Class ABC` to list ITEMS, How can i make sure its not already in ITEMS list or in its Inner Child lists and then add it to ITEMS list or any of its inner Child List?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension function `Flatten`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> flattenFn) => e.SelectMany(c => c.Flatten(flattenFn));
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this T current, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenFn) {
    var working = new Stack<T>();
    working.Push(current);

    while (working.Count > 0) {
        current = working.Pop();
        yield return current;

        if (childrenFn(current) != null)
            foreach (var child in childrenFn(current))
                working.Push(child);
    }
}
```

You can flatten your original `ITEMS` `List` and then check if your new item isn't in it:

```
var exists = ITEMS.Flatten(x => x.Child).Select(x => x.itemName).Contains(newItemID);
```

If you are doing this a lot, it may be wise to consider a hash based structure such as a `Dictionary` or if you have a unique list of items to add, creating a hash set from the flattened `ITEMS` to speed up checking.

Comment: The solution needs to be modified depending on how we define duplicate. By reference or property value.

Comment: @NetMage Sorry Im out of office, Ill check this and reply on your answer when Im in office and have my computer . tnq for respond

Answer (score 0):

Add a recursive method to the class, like this:

```
//using System.Linq;

public class ABC
(
    string itemName{get;set;}
    int parentID{get;set;}
    List<ABC> Child {get;set;}    

    public bool AlreadyContains(ABC abc)
    {
        if (Child.Any( a => a.itemName == abc.itemName )) return true;  //Check children
        return Child.Any( a => a.AlreadyContains(abc) );   //Ask children to check their children too
    }
)
```

Then you can check with one line of code:

```
if (!abc.AlreadyContains(newAbc)) abc.Add(newAbc);
```

Note: The above example assumes to abc instances are equal when their itemNames are equal. You can, of course, modify the criteria, e.g. `abc.Equals(newAbc)` is you have overridden Equals(), or `abc == newAbc` if you want reference equality.

Comment: Soryy Im out of office, Ill check this and reply on your answer when Im in office and have my computer . tnq for respond